# Are the CEO's pink drumsticks a reference?

Tags: reference, props, barbie

In *Barbie* (2023), the CEO of Mattel (played by Will Ferrell) brandishes a pair of pink drumsticks:

[image: The CEO of Mattel holding a pair of pink drumsticks in the boardroom]

As far as I remember, the CEO doesn't actually use these drumsticks for drumming or anything else in the movie (other than as a phallic symbol), but I could have missed something.

**Are the pink drumsticks a reference to something in either the Barbie universe or elsewhere?**

Comment: There was a drummer Barbie doll but the drumsticks weren't pink but it's possible it's an indirect reference.

Comment: "*pink drumsticks*"? a woman? drummer? [Sandy West](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yY8C7z9skDI) would probably have loved that reference :D RIP legendary woman. Barbie being a girls universe, pink seems the right *cliché* though.

Comment: I've seen people mentioning the Stepbrothers film

Comment: @Valorum I've just had a look at the trailer to *Step Brothers* — I will not be watching this film.  Can you (or someone else) explain the reference in an answer?

Comment: @ElementsInSpace - They're only guessing. I've not seen anything definitive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This appears to be a subtle reference to Will Ferrell's notable resemblance to drummer Chad Smith from the Red Hot Chilli Peppers.

> The striking resemblance of Chad Smith and Will Ferrell is remembered once again. In scenes from the trailer for the film Barbie , the actor appears in some moments holding drumsticks, in other words, an obvious reference to the Red Hot Chili Peppers drummer (at least that's what we believe).
>
> <sub><sup>[Chad Smith from the Chili Peppers in the movie Barbie? Will Ferrell appears holding drumsticks in scenes from the film](https://portalpopline.com.br/chad-smith-do-chili-peppers-no-filme-da-barbie-will-ferrell-aparece-segurando-baquetas-em-cenas/)</sup></sub>

The two famously had a "[drum off](https://youtu.be/0uBOtQOO70Y?si=M3LPxNQ9_swt4C6f)" on *The Tonight Show.*

> [image]

Chad Smith also appears on the film's musical credits and [official Barbie album](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbie_the_Album#:%7E:text=Butterflies%22%20(Gayle)) (credited as one of the writers of the song [Butterfly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_(Crazy_Town_song))).

Comment: Could you identify which of Smith or Ferrel it is drumming in your image?

Comment: @Darren - I believe that to be Ferrell, but you've defintely made the point about how similar they look

Comment: Might be useful to have pics of both just to prove your point :)

Comment: @Darren - There's a clicky-link to the video in the answer.

Comment: I wouldn't describe it as "subtle".